# Trouble adding stylesheet to javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm new to Java and JavaFX and have a problem here. I tried to add a css file to the javafx application, but I just get the error "Resource Style.css not found".
Most of the code is based on a tutorial I found on YouTube btw. The css file is in the same directory as the Main.java file. I'm not sure if this is the proper way to add stylesheet to javafx, but this worked on the Tutorial.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Title");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(8);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        //Name label
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Username:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameLabel, 0 ,0);

        //Name input
        TextField nameInput = new TextField("Emil");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameInput, 1, 0);

        //Password label
        Label passLabel = new Label("Password:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passLabel, 0, 1);

        //Password input
        TextField passInput = new TextField();
        passInput.setPromptText("password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passInput, 1, 1);

        //Login button
        Button loginButton = new Button("Log In");
        GridPane.setConstraints(loginButton, 1, 2);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, nameInput, passLabel, passInput, loginButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 600, 350);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your css file is in the same directory as your Main.java, try adding your css like this:

```
String css = this.getClass().getResource("Style.css")
                .toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
```

edit: as your css file is in the same dir, it should work like this. sorry, overread this sentence in your question.

usually your class files are compiled into a bin directory (if youre using eclipse), but there you don't have your css ressource, thats why it can't be found

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any idea why it worked in the youtube video and not for me? BTW, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: perhaps he set his intelliJ up to compile class files in the same folder, but better ask  in a comment to the video ;)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I found that `parent.setStyle(stylesheet)` didn't work but `parent.getStylesheets().add(css)` did work **provided** that css contains forward slashes only, not backslashes.  For example, 
`parent.getStylesheets().add("file:\\c:\\workspace\\Insights\\stylesheet1.css");` didn't work, but 
`parent.getStylesheets().add("file:/c:/workspace/Insights/stylesheet1.css")` did work.